# Pull To Refresh Stack View

Tags: swift

I want to implement a pull to refresh feature on my current UIViewController. I have 10 buttons - 5 rows of vertical stack views in one horizontal stack view to create a grid. I would like to be able to pull to refresh here to run a function and update the button labels. What are my options?

[image: Storyboard Layout]

Comment: can you show me your stackView code in your viewController? I just want to see how you hooked up the stackView

Answer (score 0):

**You can't add a refresh control into a stack view for the purpose of refreshing the content.**

The **important** thing here is you *have to* add the refresh control into a *scroll view* to let it be functional as expected:

> ### UIRefreshControl
>
> A standard control that can initiate the refreshing of a **scroll view’s**
> **contents**.
>
> <sub>[UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol)</sub>

For this case I would encourage to let your grid to be as a [***`UICollectionView`***](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) instead of stack view.

In addition, What if you tried to add another button into the grid? the container view should be scrollable, which means that a collection view would more maintainable.

---

Furthermore, you might be able to get the leverage of the [UICollectionViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller). Checking the following could be useful:

- [Is completely static UICollectionView possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524691/is-completely-static-uicollectionview-possible)
- [How to create a static UICollectionView.](https://robkerr.com/how-to-create-a-static-uicollectionview-af8ce3bf07ac)
- [How to use pull to refresh in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43525551/5501940)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to go with a `UICollectionView`. Create a custom cell to you desired needs. After that you can add a refresh controller:

```
// Global variable
let pullToRefreshData = UIRefreshControl()

// Where you initialise the collectionView (eg. viewDidAppear())
collectionView.refreshControl = pullToRefreshData
pullToRefreshData.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)

// This will be called when you pull from top of the collectionView
@objc func refreshData() {
    // Maybe you need to call a server API, stop the reloading animation when you have the data
    pullToRefreshData.endRefreshing()

    // Refresh the data from the collectionView
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

If you only need to use your implementation, maybe you can provide a context.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case I'd suggest using `UICollectionView`, which has build in support for `UIRefreshControl`. But if your buttons are somewhat different or you want a bit easier and less robust solution, you could simply embed your `UIStackView` in `UIScrollView` and set it's `refreshControl`.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2127691-refreshcontrol